# Blank Apache error with php CGI

Tags: php, apache

Here is the link between apache and httpd.conf (it's a windows server):

> Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php-cgi.exe"
>
> SetEnv PHPRC C:/project/bin/PHP5

With this configuration, when browsing my website I get sometimes this error:

> [Tue Feb 11 14:39:25 2014] [error] [client 10.0.0.56]

This error could happen on every php or html page, but not each time (about one time for 10 access).

If I use php module with this configuration in my httpd.conf:

> LoadModule php5_module "c:/project/Bin/PHP5/php5apache2.dll"
>
> PHPIniDir "c:/project/Bin/PHP5"

Errors disapear!

Where are these errors come from with my php-cgi? How could I solve this problem?

Thanks!